# Akka FSM vs Storm for media content rendering application

Tags: akka, actor, apache-storm, fsm

I have actor system with data flow route depending on passed data.

[image]

Now I want to extract common pieces of code from actors and introduce states.

Like if I want to build video with audio - then either on "ffmpeg" state  I have to wait for both messages from "PhantomJS" and "Audio", and on Amazon S3 -"PhantomJS" and "FFMPEG" arrived. But for other data sets (just video or just audio) it can simply pass through. States may be governed by several actors.

In the very past I worked with [OSWorkflow](https://java.net/projects/osworkflow) project, which seems to be dead now. I looked at Akka FSM and Twitter Storm, both seem to solve my problem, but perhaps I need some opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are actually asking for but to me ..
In a storm like environment these sources like *Video*, *Preview*, *Audio* could act as a `Spout` subscribed to a `message queue` like Kafka or kestrel. *PhantomJS* on the other hand could play the role of a `Bolt` subscribed to different spouts (Video, Preview). Same goes with the other components (*ffmpeg*, *S3*).

> I have to wait for both messages from "PhantomJS" and "Audio", and on
>   Amazon S3 -"PhantomJS" and "FFMPEG" arrived.

Is this a kind of stream joining you are looking for ? Check out [this](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Common-patterns) doc that says

> A streaming join combines two or more data streams together based on some common field. Whereas a normal database join has finite input and clear semantics for a join, a streaming join has infinite input and unclear semantics for what a join should be.

Storm [trident](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-API-Overview) also provides a very efficient ways of merging . Its as simple as `topology.merge(stream1, stream2, stream3);` 
You could probably look futher on this, hope this helps